MinGW GCC refuses to build with coverage on WSL file system
I have a set of C/C++ source files stored in a Git repository that I need to build in both WSL and Windows. It’s tempting to clone the repository once in WSL and then use a Windows compiler to build the project on the WSL filesystem mapped to a drive letter. Cloning the repository on Windows and then mounting it in WSL is not feasible because the WSL build process relies on Linux-specific features such as file permissions and symbolic symlinks.
However,  I’ve encountered compatibility issues with MinGW working on a WSL file system. Specifically, if I build with coverage enabled, gcc fails to compile producing an empty .gcno file (and no actual compiler output).
As a test sample, I have created a test.c file with an empty main() function inside ~/test/ folder. Then I map this folder to a Windows drive and try a regular compilation, which is successful:
C:\>subst X: \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\user\test
C:\>X:
X:\>type test.c
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
X:\>gcc test.c
X:\>dir
 Volume in drive X has no label.

 Directory of X:\

12/12/2024  09:09 AM                33 test.c
12/12/2024  09:48 AM    <DIR>          .
12/12/2024  09:47 AM           119,591 a.exe
12/12/2024  09:48 AM    <DIR>          ..
               2 File(s)        119,624 bytes

However, compiling with coverage fails:
X:\>erase a.exe
X:\>gcc --coverage test.c
test.c: error: cannot open a-test.gcno
X:\>dir
 Volume in drive X has no label.

 Directory of X:\

12/12/2024  09:09 AM                33 test.c
12/12/2024  10:24 AM    <DIR>          .
12/12/2024  10:24 AM    <DIR>          ..
12/12/2024  10:24 AM                 0 a-test.gcno
               2 File(s)             33 bytes

Running GCC directly from a WSL folder also fails if --coverage is used:
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\user\test> gcc .\test.c
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\user\test> Test-Path a.exe
True
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\user\test> gcc --coverage .\test.c
.\test.c: error: cannot open a-test.gcno

This happens with the latest GCC from MSYS2, however, older versions are also affected (I tested GCC 10.4 and 12.2 with the same result as above). I also tried 32-bit builds and C++ builds, with the same outcome. I only tested this on WSL2 with Ubuntu 22 distro though.
X:\>gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Tools/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-14.2.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --enable-bootstrap --enable-checking=release --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,fortran,ada,objc,obj-c++,rust,jit --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts --enable-libstdcxx-time --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-libssp --disable-multilib --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-plugin --with-boot-ldflags=-static-libstdc++ --with-stage1-ldflags=-static-libstdc++
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 14.2.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)

X:\>wsl --version
WSL version: 2.1.5.0
Kernel version: 5.15.146.1-2
WSLg version: 1.0.60
MSRDC version: 1.2.5105
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22631.4460

X:\>wsl --list
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu-22.04 (Default)

I know I can successfully compile by copying test.c to a Windows drive, or by disabling coverage. But is there a way for me to compile with coverage and without copying my code back and forth between Windows drive and WSL? I also have GCC-specific options in my build scripts (including, but not limited to --coverage), so switching to a different compiler is not worth it for me.
I would be especially grateful if someone could get GCC to work with a different WSL version, or perhaps point me to some Windows/WSL settings that could help.

WSL + Win + MSYS2 - real messy environment you have there, which makes this a good XY Problem candidate. Pick one (e.g. WSL) and do everything from there.

@CristiFati Unfortunately, Windows build relies on some closed-source code generation tools which don't understand paths starting with \\wsl.localhost\. Additionally, cross-compiling Windows executables in WSL also gets messy in non-trivial cases. And the WSL build, like I already mentioned, uses symlinks and bash scripts which would be a pain to deal with without WSL.

Symbolic links from NTFS work well inside WSL. Permissions should work as well with proper mount options.

@Philippe Symlinks and permissions are just the tip of the iceberg. The next problem I encountered is fatal: '/mnt/c/test/test.c' is outside repository at 'C:\test\' when trying to use source control in VS Code running in WSL on a Git repo cloned in Windows. Most of our developers use WSL and VS Code, so working with a Windows repo will not be acceptable from them. I'd rather stick to my initial plan to get the Windows build working with a WSL repo.

@Philippe And the situation with symlinks is not that rosy on Windows either: according to this they only work if I run Git as admin or enable developer mode, neither of which is a perfect solution.

Are you sure ? The post you linked is almost 10 years old. Please try and post results. Are you using MSYS2 or MinGW ?

@Philippe It's partially successful: I tried out cmake -E create_symlink test.c test2.c. This command works in WSL inside /mnt/c/test/. As a side note, in Windows when executed in C:\test\, it fails with "CMake Error: failed to create symbolic link 'test2.c': A required privilege is not held by the client."

@Philippe Nevertheless, like I already mentioned, it's not the only issue: VS Code refusing to work with a Windows repo from WSL is much worse than my original problem. I'd rather instruct developers to clone the repo twice and keep the two copies in sync than tell them that they need to open one VS Code instance from WSL to work on their code, and another VS Code instance in Windows just for source control.

Are you using MSYS2 or MinGW ?

@Philippe I simply add C:\Tools\msys64\mingw64\bin to my PATH and then call gcc. I suppose that means I use MinGW rather than MSYS2.

gcc uses _locking when creating gcno files. This is implemented via LockFileEx, which isn't supported by WSL.
